# Print an array between two given characters

Tags: c

I have a file and i need to print the part between two given characters z1 and z2. I know how to print after the first one but i have no idea how to stop printing when z2 is met.

NOTE: The wtf function is written from the exercise.

I've tried `if(niz == z2) {break;}` but it doesn't seem to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void wtf() {
    FILE *f = fopen("podatoci.txt", "w");
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '#') {
        fputc(c, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    wtf();
    getchar();
    char c, z1, z2;
    scanf("%c %c", &z1, &z2);
    FILE *fo = fopen("podatoci.txt", "r");
    char niz[80];
    char *a;
    while(fgets(niz, 80, fo) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", strchr(niz, z1) + 1);

    }   
    fclose(fo);

    return 0;
}
```

I need the array to stop printing when it hits z2.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function `wtf`? It is not used anywhere in `main`. Why did you include it? "_I know how to print after the first one..._" - please include your attempt.

Comment: `if(niz == z2) {break;}` is missing from the posted code.  Post the true code that you are having trouble.

Comment: Your `fgets` statement puts 80 characters at once in `niz`, so there’s no way the `niz == z2` statement could be true (it compares an 80-character array to a single character). You’ll have to go through the file’s contents one character at a time (though you can read them from the file in larger blocks).

Comment: What guarantees that `z1` and `z2` will be within the same ***line*** of input as will be read by `fgets`?

Comment: OT: always check the returned value from C library functions to assure no error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to locating the characters (if any) between `z1` and `z2` entered by the user within a buffer read from a file is to validate:

- that `z1` exists in the buffer (saving the location for later use);
- that `z2` exists in the remaining section of the buffer (saving the location for later use); and finally
- that `z2` is not the next character after `z1` in the buffer - meaning that at least 1 valid character exists between `z1` and `z2`.

While you can use `fgets` (and I would suggest it), to simplify the example, let's use POSIX `getline` to avoid having to allocate/reallocate manually to insure a complete line is read (regardless of the length). If you know the maximum number of characters you will read from the file in advance, then you can simply use a fixed size buffer and use the input function of your choice.

After reading all characters in a line into your buffer, it is then a simple matter of locating `z1` and `z2` within the buffer. `strchr` will search the buffer for the existence of each character returning a pointer within the buffer if the character is found (or `NULL` if the character is not found). You simply save the pointer returned by `strchr` in each case which leaves you with a pointer (1-char before) and (1-char after) the characters ***between*** `z1` and `z2`.

(hint: if you increment `p1` it will point to the first character you want)

Then it is just a matter of allocating storage to hold the characters between `p1` and `p2` and using `memcpy` to copy the characters to the new storage (remembering to *nul-terminate* the resulting buffer) before outputting your results. Again, if using a fixed size buffer to hold the line read from the file, then a second buffer of equal size is sufficient to hold the characters between `z1` and `z2`.

Putting it altogether you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char z1, z2,        /* user input characters */
        *p1, *p2,       /* pointers to bracket z1, z2 in buf */
        *buf = NULL,    /* buffer to hold line read from file */
        *btwn = NULL;   /* buffer to hold chars between z1, z2 */
    size_t n = 0;       /* allocation size (0 - getline decides) */
    FILE *fp = NULL; 

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate filename provided as argument */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <file>\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");      /* open file */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    /* prompt, read/validate 2 non-whitespace characters entered */
    fputs ("enter beginning and ending characters: ", stdout);
    if (scanf (" %c %c", &z1, &z2) != 2) {
        fputs ("(input canceled before 2 characters read)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (getline (&buf, &n, fp) == -1) { /* read line from file into buf */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: reading from '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file */

    p1 = strchr (buf, z1);  /* locate z1 in buf */
    if (p1 == NULL) {       /* validate pointer not NULL */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: '%c' not found in buf.\n", z1);
        return 1;
    }   /* locate/validate z2 found after z1 in buf */
    else if ((p2 = strchr (p1, z2)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: '%c' not found after '%c' in buf.\n",
                z2, z1);
        return 1;
    }   /* validate z2 is not next char after z1 */
    else if (p2 - p1 == 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: '%c' is next char after '%c' in buf.\n",
                z2, z1);
        return 1;
    }
    p1++;   /* increment p1 to point to 1st char between z1 & z2 */

    /* allocate mem for chars between p1 & p2 */
    if ((btwn = malloc (p2 - p1 + 1)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc-btwn");
        return 1;
    }

    memcpy (btwn, p1, p2 - p1); /* copy characters between p1 & p2 */
    btwn[p2 - p1] = 0;          /* nul-terminate btwn */

    printf ("between: '%s'\n", btwn);   /* output results */

    free (btwn);    /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */
    free (buf);
}
```

**Example Input/File**

```
$ cat ../dat/qbfox.txt
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: j s
between: 'ump'

$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: A f
between: ' quick brown '
```

Error in order:

```
$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: s j
error: 'j' not found after 's' in buf.
```

Either character not in buf:

```
$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: B z
error: 'B' not found in buf.

$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: A B
error: 'B' not found after 'A' in buf.
```

Nothing between `z1` and `z2`:

```
$ ./bin/findcharsbtwn ../dat/qbfox.txt
enter beginning and ending characters: w n
error: 'n' is next char after 'w' in buf.
```

(don't forget to validate your memory use with a tool such as `valgrind` on Linux)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.